# Tensorflow Transfer Learning with Input Pipeline

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to use transfer learning with Google's Inception network for an image recognition problem. I am using [`retrain.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py) from the TensorFlow example source for inspiration.

In `retrain.py`, the Inception graph is loaded and a feed dict is used to feed the new images into the model's input layer. However, I have my data serialized in TFRecord files and have been using an input pipeline to feed in my inputs, as demonstrated [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/reading_data/#reading_from_files).

So I have a tensor `images` which returns my input data in batches when run. But how can I feed these images into Inception? I can't use a feed dict since my inputs are tensors, not NumPy arrays. My two ideas are

1) simply call `sess.run()` on each batch to convert it to a NumPy array, and then use a feed dict to pass it to Inception.

2) replace the input node in the Inception graph with my own batch input tensor

I think (1) would work, but it seems a little inelegant. (2) seems more natural to me, but I can't do exactly that because TensorFlow graphs can only be appended to and not otherwise modified.

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement option (2), replacing the input node, but you will need to modify `retrain.py` to do so. The [`tf.import_graph_def()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/framework/utility_functions#import_graph_def) function supports a limited form of modification to the imported graph, by *remapping* tensors in the imported graph to existing tensors in the target graph.

[This line in `retrain.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2607cc67f0e4a6cd313399e1f68cc4b9857fe700/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py#L254) calls `tf.import_graph_def()` to import the Inception model, where `jpeg_data_tensor` becomes the tensor that you feed with input data:

```
bottleneck_tensor, jpeg_data_tensor, resized_input_tensor = (
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='', return_elements=[
        BOTTLENECK_TENSOR_NAME, JPEG_DATA_TENSOR_NAME,
        RESIZED_INPUT_TENSOR_NAME]))
```

Instead of retrieving `jpeg_data_tensor` from the imported graph, you can remap it to an input pipeline that you construct yourself:

```
# Output of a training pipeline, returning a `tf.string` tensor containing
# a JPEG-encoded image.
jpeg_data_tensor = ...

bottleneck_tensor, resized_input_tensor = (
    tf.import_graph_def(
        graph_def,
        input_map={JPEG_DATA_TENSOR_NAME: jpeg_data_tensor},
        return_elements=[BOTTLENECK_TENSOR_NAME, RESIZED_INPUT_TENSOR_NAME]))
```

Wherever you previously fed `jpeg_data_tensor`, you no longer need to need it, because the inputs will be read from the input pipeline  you constructed. (Note that you might need to handle `resized_input_tensor` as well... I'm not intimately familiar with `retrain.py`, so some restructuring might be necessary.)

Comment: Thanks, the `input_map` parameter of `import_graph_def` was exactly what I was looking for. Computing and caching bottlenecks is now many times faster than with option (1).